# convert local date time to UTC as yy:mm:dd H:M format

Tags: javascript

I need to convert local date to UTC or ISO date fromat as yy:mm:dd H:M or date diff locale date time with 03:30 as yy:mm:dd  H:M

> 2016-10-22T04:30:00.000Z

convert to

> 2016-10-22T01:00:00.000Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but if you need to subtract 3:30 from a Date object and display it in ISO format then something like this should work.

(you don't need datejs.com)

```js
function subtractTime(dateObj, hours, mins) {
  dateObj.setHours(dateObj.getHours() - hours);
  dateObj.setMinutes(dateObj.getMinutes() - mins);
}

var date = new Date('2016-10-22T04:30:00.000Z');
subtractTime(date, 3, 30);
console.log(date.toISOString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check out datejs: http://www.datejs.com/. Then you can do,

```
Date.parse('2016-10-22T04:30:00.000Z').addHours(-3).addMinutes(-30). toISOString()
// 2016-10-22T04:30:00.000Z
```